# Difference two dataframes based on two columns Python Panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Df1 

 A B C
 1  1 'a'
 2  3 'b'
 3  4 'c'

Df2
  A  B  C
  1  1 'k'
  5  4 'e'
```

Expected output (after difference and merge of Df1 and Df2)
   i.e. Df1-Df2 and then merge

```
output 

     A B C
     1  1 'a'
     2  3 'b'
     3  4 'c'
     5  4 'e'
```

The difference should be based on two columns A and B and not all three columns. I do not care what column C contains in both Df2 and Df1.

Comment: Why should the new dataframe have `1,1,"a"` and not `1,1,"k"`? Is there a criteria for column C? Should column C be dropped?

Comment: It is like set difference. Left operand values should be there.

Comment: why is `5, 4, 'e'` there?

Comment: it is difference and merge.

Comment: Yes, but you need a criteria for handling column C, or you need to drop it.  Should it always be the first dataframe's column C value?  The seconds?  Randomly pick?

Comment: @JeffL: I have said left operand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an outer join, then merging in column C from df2 if a value is not known in df1:

```
dfx = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['A', 'B'])
dfx['C'] = dfx.apply(
     lambda r: r.C_x if not pd.isnull(r.C_x) else r.C_y, axis=1)
dfx[['A', 'B', 'C']]
=>
   A  B  C
0  1  1  a
1  2  3  b
2  3  4  c
3  5  4  e
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
In [44]: df1.set_index(['A','B']).combine_first(df2.set_index(['A','B'])).reset_index()
Out[44]:
   A  B    C
0  1  1  'a'
1  2  3  'b'
2  3  4  'c'
3  5  4  'e'
```

Comment: Kudos to you for figuring out what the OP was thinking.  But isn't this more like set addition? +1

Comment: @piRSquared, yes, I think you are right. But let's see whether it's OK for OP or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using concat and drop_duplicates:

```
output = pd.concat([df1, df2])
output = output.drop_duplicates(subset = ["A", "B"], keep = 'first')
```

*** Desired df: ***

```
   A  B  C
0  1  1  a
1  2  3  b
2  3  4  c
1  5  4  e
```